# Add value from DDL to DB with MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I had an `ASP.NET MVC Razor` project and I have `DropDownList` which have data from `Database`, and I tried to insert the selected value from `DropDownList` to `Database` but I couldn't .

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Parent_ID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field create-Bt3">
   @Html.DropDownList("-Select Parent-", new SelectList(ViewBag.Parent, "Value", "Text"),"- Select Parent -")

    </div>
```

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var data = db.Categories.ToList().Distinct();
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var t in data)
        {
            SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = t.Name;
            s.Value = t.Cat_ID.ToString();
            items.Add(s);
        }
        ViewBag.Parent = items;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category category, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];

            var fileSavePath = "";
            var fileName = "";


            fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
            fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/" + fileName);

            uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
            category.Path = "~/App_Data/Uploads/" + fileName;
        }

        category.Add_Date = DateTime.Now;
        category.Last_Update = DateTime.Now;

        db.Categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want to get ParentID(selected value of DDL)? If yes, you should add param in your action with name same as that of DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `onchange` event of the `DropDownList`.

```
@Html.DropDownList("-Select Parent-", new SelectList(ViewBag.Parent, "Value", "Text"),"- Select Parent -",new { @onchange="submitData(this);" } )
```

Now in your javascript, pass that data using `$.ajax` to your controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function submitData(e){
   $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Home")',
                data: ({ selectedValue: e.innerHTML }),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
                return false;
   });
 }
</script>
```

Then in your controller add a parameter in addition.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string selectedValue, Category category, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
   //Do Database stuff to insert the selected value to DB
}
```

Comment: ok, i got you. In you `Create` action method instead of returning View return as `return Json(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead use this code:

In your view bind dropdown like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User, new SelectList(Model.UserList, "Value", "Text"), new { @tabindex = "2" })
```

And create properties in model like this:

```
public string User{ get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> UserList{ get; set; }
```

And fetch data from databae to bind your dropdown like this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetUserTypeList()
{
        List<SelectListItem> listUsers = new List<SelectListItem>();
        using (DbCommand command = DataAccess.CreateCommandTypeSPWithOutputCursor())
        {
            command.CommandText = "GetUserList";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;               
            DataSet objDataSet = DataAccess.GetDataset(command);
            foreach (DataRow row in objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                SelectListItem user = new SelectListItem();
                user.Text = Convert.ToString(row["UserName"]).Trim();
                user.Value = Convert.ToString(row["UserID"]).Trim();
                listUsers.Add(user);
            }
        }
        return listUsers;
    }
```

In controller action method assign UserList to the method GetUserTypeList() and in the last don't forget to put your entire html in form method like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) {
...
}
```

So this how you can post your drop down selected value to the database.